# PHP What object oriented function can replace mysql_insert_id()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$run = $con->query ( $query );
$id = mysql_insert_id ();


//find category Name
    $category = $_REQUEST ['category'];
    $run1 = $con->query ("select * from category where id='$category'");
    $run2=$run1->fetch_array();
    $category=$run2['category'];
    
//find  subcategory Name
$run11 = $con->query ("select * from subcategory where id='$subcategory'");
$run21=$run11->fetch_array();
$subcategory=$run21['subcategory'];
```

Comment: What type is `$con`?

Comment: your cod eis **vunerable** to **sql injection** so use only **prepared statements with paramaters**

Comment: Reading the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) will be an invaluable experience to learn about these transitions.

Comment: If you are changing the old mysql_* API then I would recommend changing it to PDO. Why bother with mysqli?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [mysqli::$insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php). mysql_insert_id() was part of the now deprecared mysql-extension.

Comment: so, `$con->insert_id`